# Which US Presidents travelled around the world?

Tags: united-states, president, travel

Shortly after President Grant left office, he went on a round-the-world journey, with stops all over Europe, in Russia, through the Suez Canal, to China and Japan, arriving in San Francisco and then crossing the North American continent.

I believe he was the first US President (or former President) to do so.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am guessing such journeys have become more common as travels have gotten easier and cheaper (Grant spent something like $25,000 for his journey).

Which other Presidents have made a round-the-world journey as a single trip?

My information about President Grant is from Jean Edward Smith's wonderful *Grant*.

Comment: Are you including years before they were president?  If so, there are probably a number of post WWII presidents who did so as part of their service.

Comment: Taft putting on a belt.

Comment: I would include years before, during or after their presidential service.  I'm curious about any such trips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franklin Pierce beat Grant by a decade...

**After Office..**

- in 1857 **Franklin Pierce** retired from the presidency and [left on a grandiose vacation](http://www.thisisinsider.com/what-presidents-did-after-leaving-office-2016-11#john-quincy-adams-became-a-political-junkie-2) to Madeira, Portugal, Spain, France, Switzerland, and Rome, where he met up with his longtime buddy, Nathaniel Hawthorne.
- In 1913 — four years after he left the Oval Office — **Teddy Roosevelt** took part in an expedition to South America, promising to hunt and bring back animal specimens for display in the American Museum of Natural History.  He caught Malaria and nearly died.

**In Office**

- **Theodore Roosevelt** was the [first commander in chief to travel outside the U.S. on official business](http://www.history.com/news/ask-history/who-was-the-first-u-s-president-to-travel-abroad-while-in-office), when he sailed to Panama in November 1906.

Comment: Some interesting tidbits but the question says 'around the world' and 'a round-the-world journey as a single trip'.